# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row on laravel migration

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I'm addign a foreign key to my `appointments` table, my DB is called `arl` through laravel migrations

but when I run migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::table('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->foreign('order_detail_id')->references('id')->on('order_details');
        
    });
}
```

I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`arl`.`#sql-5470_6`, CONSTRAINT `appointments_order_detail_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`order_detail_id`) REFERENCES `order_details` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `appointments` add constraint `appointments_order_detail_id_foreign` foreign key (`order_detail_id`) references `order_details` (`id`))
```

checking the error I don't know why the sql doesn't recognize my table name and put this weird name `` arl`.`#sql-5470_6 `` should be `` arl`.`appointments ``

I went to heidi sql to replicate de query and I got the same error.

Edit: the problem it's on laragon local serve I tried with xampp and worked fine

Comment: Please add table defintion for order_details and appointments.

Answer (score 1):

You must delete all rows in table `order_details` and try again.

Or:

```
add ->default( any id from table order_details)
$table->unsignedBigInteger('order_detail_id')->default(1);
$table->foreign('order_detail_id')->references('id')->on('order_details');
```

Comment: >You must delete all rows in table order_details and try again.

This was the solution of my problem

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_detail_id');
    $table->foreign('order_detail_id')->references('id')->on('order_details');
```

Comment: the problem it's with the table name, I don't know why sql is taking my table name as `#sql-5470_6`